# Mutation of Finalizer state

Tags: apex, asynchronous, queueable-apex, transaction-finalizers

Below is the statement from [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_transaction_finalizers.htm):

> The Finalizer framework uses the state of the Finalizer object, if one
> is attached, at the end of Queueable execution. **Mutation of the
> Finalizer state, after it’s attached, is therefore supported.**

It may be a naïve question, but what does it mean? Can someone help with an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why the documentation calls this out is that other types of Apex do *not* behave this way.

```
public class QueueableFun implements Queueable {
  public Integer counter = 0;
  public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
    System.debug(counter);
  }
}
```

...

```
QueueableFun q = new QueueableFun();
System.enqueueJob(q);
q.counter = 10;
```

...

The result of the Queueable's debug statement will be 0, not 10, as a naive developer might expect. We say that the Queueable object is serialized at the moment it is queued.

Finalizers, on the other hand, will have the correct state in the finalizer handler, no matter when you mutate its state. This is valuable, because you can keep track of which data was already processed, what errors were encountered, etc.

So, for example, with a finalizer, you can:

```
public class LoggingFinalizer implements Finalizer { ... }

public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
  LoggingFinalizer logger = new LoggingFinalizer();
  System.attachFinalizer(logger);
  for(Integer i = 10; i >= 0; i--) {
    logger.log(10.0/i); // Yes, we're going to divide by zero
  }
}
```

In the finalizer handler, you'll see that the numbers 10 to 1 were logged, even though an uncaught exception occurred.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation 

Answer (score 6):

Fundamentally this is letting the developer know that if they have a class that implements both Queueable and Finalizer, where the Queueable "attaches" itself as its own finalizer, any state that the queueable maintains in instance variables, even after attaching the finalizer, is available to the finalizer when it is actually invoked after the queueable terminates.

So, if you are writing a chaining queueable, for example, and need to keep track of where the chaining has got to (in "state" held in instance variable(s)), changes made to this state after attaching the finalizer will be visible to the finalizer implementation so it can pick up the chaining where it left off, regardless of success or failure.

The same holds true if the finalizer is a separately implemented class and the queueable maintains its state in the finalizer instance, though such an implementation separation is a bit more cumbersome.